"She turns her head to look at him, play in her eyes."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 10)

William feels his spine against the cold wall, the floor bearing into his bony backside. He cklaps his shins, his body a tight, clutched package, while Harry and Jimmy look down at him. He notices that his shoes are filthy.
Betty sits next to William, legs outstretched, prises one hand from his leg and hold it in her lap.
'To be honest,' she says, 'I feel the same when the Beatles come on. I can't stand them.' She turns her head to look at him, play in her eyes. 'I'm going to do this next time my husband starts dancing around like an idiot to "Yellow Submarine".'

I don't have any idea what play means in play in her eyes in this context. I would like to interpret it as badinage or josh/joke but there isn't any corresponding information in the dictionaries.

Playfulness is a more prosaic word.

I can stand them?? Please check for other typos. You can basically have any type of "non-concrete" noun there. death in her eyes, life in her eyes, love in her eyes, So why not play?

@ Lambie - Yes, but the issue I had was the meaning: What do you understand by "play" in "play in her eyes"?

Presumably it's something horrible that has made William collapse.  Betty is trying to cheer him up by talking light-heartedly about not liking the Beatles, so play does indeed imply badinage (Oxford says 'behaviour or speech that is not intended seriously').

As Kate said, it's in MW.

As suggested in your comments, play should imply playfulness in your excerpt.
This is a more poetic style of writing that isn't necessarily intended to be entirely literal, more giving the feeling of play as an idea, a word with many meanings. Just as people write that someone has fear in their eyes, you can write that someone has play in their eyes to describe the emotional sense of an expression.
